# .hasNext() wont turn false

Tags: java, file

I have the following code and I cannot understand why `.hasNext()` wont turn false. I am reading from a file called test.

My code:

```
package printing;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Printer {
    public int count() throws Exception{
        int num = 0;
        File f = new File("C:\\Users\\bob\\Desktop\\test.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(f);
        while (in.hasNext()){
            num++;
        }
        return num;
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Printer mine = new Printer();
        System.out.println(mine.count());
    }
}
```

File content:

4
4
6
3
8
8
8

What is wrong?

Comment: `hasNext()` is not the same as `next()`..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to consume the input from the Scanner

```
while (in.hasNext()){
    in.next();
    num++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't consume any of the input.  [`hasNext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29) doesn't consume any input.

> The scanner does not advance past any input.

Add a call to [`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) inside the `while` loop to consume the input.